# I can't get my onclick button to display anything

Tags: javascript, onclick, calculator

Okay, so I'm trying to learn a bit of JavaScript over the summer, for fun.. I've got a pretty old book, "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" that was printed back in 2002.. Well, I copied their first "trial" script word for word (or so I think heh) and I still can't get anything to display when I click the "onclick" button... More then likely, I've made some sort of syntax error, but there's always the possibility that the book might be too out of date also.. Anyways, here's what I've got:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
            function calculate() {

            var principal = document.loandata.principal.value;
            var interest = document.loandata.interest.value / 100 / 12;
            var payments = document.loandata.years.value * 12;


            var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
            var monthly = (principal*x*interest)/(x-1);


                document.loandata.payment.value = round(monthly);
                document.loandata.total.value = round(monthly * payments);
                document.loandata.totalinterest.value =
                    round((monthly * payments) - principal);
                }

                else {
                    document.loandata.payment.value = "";
                    document.loandata.total.value = "";
                    document.loandata.totalinterest.value = "";
                }
            }


                function round(x) {
                    return Math.round(x*100)/100;
                }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm completely new to this.. So any help would be appreciated.. Also, I'm sorry if this has been asked before.. I looked through other similar questions and couldn't get it resolved.. In all likeliness this is a simple syntax error that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?  There's no "onclick" button in there ;)

Comment: Please make a [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) that contains the HTML and Javascript so we can execute it.

Comment: The code seems to be correct. However, it does not seem to be attached to the document in any way, nor does it seem to be invoked in any way (unless there's an `onclick="calculate()"` or something else in your HTML). I also assume you have a form and some input fields that you didn't bother to show; if not, that would also be a problem.

Comment: When Javascript isn't working, the first thing you should do is open the browser's Developer Tools to see if there are any error messages. In this case, you would see a syntax error because part of the code is missing.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm posting the HTML part of the code and it doesn't let me display it.. Any clue why?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `else` statement without an opening `if`

```
if (/*your conditino here*/)
     round((monthly * payments) - principal);
}

else {
    document.loandata.payment.value = "";
    document.loandata.total.value = "";
    document.loandata.totalinterest.value = "";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean @Barmar?

Comment: I suspect the `if` is in the real code, but when he was pasting it into the SO question part of the code got lost.

Comment: Notice that there's an extra `}` before `else`, and several lines of indented code before that. I think there was an `if (something) {` before those indented lines.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an if statement in there.

```
function calculate() {

    var principal = document.loandata.principal.value;
    var interest = document.loandata.interest.value / 100 / 12;
    var payments = document.loandata.years.value * 12;


    var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
    var monthly = (principal*x*interest)/(x-1);

    // You're missing an if statement here?
    if ('something' == 'something') {
        document.loandata.payment.value = round(monthly);
        document.loandata.total.value = round(monthly * payments);
        document.loandata.totalinterest.value = round((monthly * payments) - principal);
    } else {
        document.loandata.payment.value = "";
        document.loandata.total.value = "";
        document.loandata.totalinterest.value = "";
    }
}


function round(x) {
    return Math.round(x*100)/100;
}
```